# iphone - Is it possible to display multiple annotations simultaneously?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have annotation views all over the map and tapping on one will display the annotation and tapping another will close first and open the second annotation. (normal behavior)

Is it possible to have all the annotations (titles, subtitles) show on initial load?

Comment: I am actually referring to having simultaneous callouts displayed on the map.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES, you can display multiple annotations!